# pythonOCC set default units to inches

Tags: python, python-3.x, step

PLEASE SEE EDIT FOR SHORT VERSION

Been hunting through the pythonOCC documentation for this.

I have .step file in inches. Here are the lines in the .step file for confirmation:

```
#50 =  ( CONVERSION_BASED_UNIT( 'INCH', #122 )LENGTH_UNIT(  )NAMED_UNIT( #125 ) );
#51 =  ( NAMED_UNIT( #127 )PLANE_ANGLE_UNIT(  )SI_UNIT( $, .RADIAN. ) );
#52 =  ( NAMED_UNIT( #127 )SI_UNIT( $, .STERADIAN. )SOLID_ANGLE_UNIT(  ) );
~~~
#122 = LENGTH_MEASURE_WITH_UNIT( LENGTH_MEASURE( 25.4000000000000 ), #267 );
```

File reads and displays in window:
[image: Display window]

When I use manual coordinates to make a bounding box, I find my box is wayyyy off:

[image: Tiny Bounding Box!]

Position is off because the STEP model is not at 0,0,0.

Turns out pythonOCC automatically converts everything into MM. When I manually enter in box dimensions in INCHES, it reads them as MM. I've tried to deal by converting everything manually too (inches * 25.4) but this is problematic and ugly.

I know pythonOCC uses the STEP file line # 122 as the conversion ratio as I've changed it from above to:

```
#122 = LENGTH_MEASURE_WITH_UNIT( LENGTH_MEASURE( 1.0 ), #267 );
```

When I do, my bounding box and step model line up perfectly... But I still know PythonOCC thinks it's converting to MM.

[image: Perfect!... but in MM]

Anyone have any experience changing the default units for pythonocc?
I've tried to find in the following occ packages:
    OCC.STEPControl, OCC.Display, OCC.AIS
and many others.

EDIT:

When I draw my box using my own coordinates like this:

```
minPoint = gp_Pnt(minCoords)
maxPoint = gp_Pnt(maxCoords)
my_box = AIS_Shape(BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox(minPoint, maxPoint).Shape())
display.Context.Display(my_box.GetHandle())
```

My coordinates are in Inches, but pythonOCC reads them as MM. If I can get my own coordinates to be read in Inches, this would be solved. Can't find anything in OCC.Display for how my coordinates are interpreted. Something like "OCC.Display.*inputUnitsAre("INCHES")*"?

EDIT 2:

Getting closer looking here:

https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/refman/html/class_units_a_p_i.html

Under UnitsAPI_SystemUnits and SetCurrentUnit... Though I'm not sure how to implement in python yet to test. Working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find documentation for the [`units here`](https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/overview/html/occt_user_guides__step.html)

Take a look at the `OCC.Extended.DataExchange` module, you'll see the following function:

```
def write_step_file(a_shape, filename, application_protocol="AP203"):
    """ exports a shape to a STEP file
    a_shape: the topods_shape to export (a compound, a solid etc.)
    filename: the filename
    application protocol: "AP203" or "AP214"
    """
    # a few checks
    assert not a_shape.IsNull()
    assert application_protocol in ["AP203", "AP214IS"]
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        print("Warning: %s file already exists and will be replaced" % filename)
    # creates and initialise the step exporter
    step_writer = STEPControl_Writer()
    Interface_Static_SetCVal("write.step.schema", "AP203")

    # transfer shapes and write file
    step_writer.Transfer(a_shape, STEPControl_AsIs)
    status = step_writer.Write(filename)

    assert status == IFSelect_RetDone
    assert os.path.isfile(filename)
```

By default, `OCC` writes units in millimeters, so I'm curious what function / method was used to export your `STEP` file.

```
Interface_Static_SetCVal("Interface_Static_SetCVal("write.step.unit","MM")
```

The docs though state that this methods `Defines a unit in which the STEP file should be written. If set to unit other than MM, the model is converted to these units during the translation.`, so having to explicitly set this unit is unexpected.

Comment: Unfortunately, the step files are generated by cad cam software. I don't have control over that. I'm parsing the step file manually alongside using python OCC. not exactly elegant, but I can see what I need line by line. I'm mostly using OCC to give me a visual and make overlays. Is there a better way to 'extract' the coordinates of features using occ? 

I will take your insight to see if I can dig a liitle deeper... in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I THINK I got it. Your answer helped me look in the right place for where to change this setting. I'll report back once I know I've change the units. But for now, this worked for me before reading the step file:

Interface_Static_SetIVal("read.step.product.mode",0)

Comment: Nevermind, that didn't do it. Maybe I need to set units after changing the product mode to 0. With xstep.cascade.unit? trying to see how and where to set this in pythonOCC.

Comment: I can confirm none of the above solves the problem. I need my own coordinates (not from the file) interpreted as inches. See edit.

Thanks for your answer though.... I need to get better at knowing what my OWN question is so I can ask more straightforward questions.